# Fix for blinking Nvidia GTX 460m?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, laptop

I have an Asus G73-JW Laptop and on official drivers, it will blink every time that the Powermizer will change the speed of the card. The only workaround I have found so far is to set it to maximum performance but, this is not a viable workaround as it is always maxed out so, lots of heat...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try playing with the Nvidia setting...

[image]

Comment: Update to the newest drivers, tried different settings but still, when it change speed (powermizer) it will blink and only setting it to maximum performances prevent it :(

Answer (score 1):

Manually add this line to your xorg.conf file:

```
Option     "RegistryDwords" "PowerMizerEnable=0x1; PerfLevelSrc=0x3322; PowerMizerDefaultAC=0x1"
```

EXAMPLE:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 460M"
    Option     "RegistryDwords" "PowerMizerEnable=0x1; PerfLevelSrc=0x3322; PowerMizerDefaultAC=0x1"
EndSection
```

Comment: What does it do ? Does it only set the card to Maximum performance or it really fix the blinking when switching gpu frequency ?

Comment: Sets it to Max Performance when on AC Power.